# Equivalent PHP code in C#

Tags: c#, php, equivalent

I know that `$_POST['m_orderid']` in C# the equivalent will be `Request.Form["m_orderid"]`. 
What means in C#:

```
$_POST['m_orderid'].'|success';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to concatenate `Request.Form["m_orderid"]` with this string: `|success`, so the equivalent syntax in C# would be:

```
Request.Form["m_orderid"] + "|success";
```